# My gRPC-Test Project just work on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

i have the following problem.

I created a gRpc Server(*Console App .Net 4.7.2 - i cant do Net Core on Server Side because of Crystal Reports :(*) and a Client(*WPF App .Net Core 3.1*) and i can run it as long as Server and Client are on my machine (Windows 10). As far es i take my Server to another machine (windows Server 2016), it does not work anymore.

this is the RPC Exception:

> Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all
> addresses",
> DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException:
> {"created":"@1595508082.170000000","description":"Failed to pick
> subchannel","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595508082.170000000","description":"failed
> to connect to all
> addresses","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}")

i tried all variations. Here is my lastcode that works on localhost:

Server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"root.crt");
        var servercert = File.ReadAllText(@"server.crt");
        var serverkey = File.ReadAllText(@"server.key");
        var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(servercert, serverkey);
        var sslCredentials = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>() { keypair }, cacert, false);

        // Build a server
        var server = new Server
        {
            Services = { ReportService.BindService(new KKarteReportService()) },
            Ports = { new ServerPort(Host, Port, sslCredentials) }
        };


        // Start server
        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("KKarteReport Server listening on port " + Port);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
    }
```

Client

```
var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"root.crt");
var clientcert = File.ReadAllText(@"client.crt");
var clientkey = File.ReadAllText(@"client.key");
var ssl = new SslCredentials(cacert, new KeyCertificatePair(clientcert, clientkey));
           
 var options = new List<ChannelOption> { new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.SslTargetNameOverride, "MyServerHost") }; 
 var channel = new Channel("12.20.18.11", 5001, ssl, options);
 //var channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, ssl, options);
 //var channel = new Channel(url, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
 var client = new ReportService.ReportServiceClient(channel);

  using var streamingCall = client.CreateAusschreibung(request);

  await using var ms = new MemoryStream();

  while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
  {
        ms.Write(streamingCall.ResponseStream.Current.FileChunk.ToByteArray());
  }
```

What do i miss?

Comment: Sorry if this may seem too obvious, but since I have faced similar server/client problems in the past, I think it's valid to ask: have you checked the firewall configurations on both sides?

Comment: Yeah, checked it multiple times. If i use a wcf service or oldschool rpc calls on this port  it works...

Comment: Http2 is requirement for gRPC and Https is requiremnt for HTTP2. try switching context to `Http2UnencryptedSupport` and `Http2Support` to false.

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan do you mean i need to do this in my wpf client or on server side or both? i'm rly new to this gRPC stuff and i have to do the server as NET4.7.2 and the client wpf Core 3.1. Can you set up a running testproject with these requirements? :)

Comment: @blindmeis only on client. For testing purposes you can use [BloomRPC](https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc)

Comment: @blindmeis what are your Host and Port values on the backed? can you confirm that you can establish TCP connection to the port on the server from client machine (using telnet, c# or anything else)? This is very likely network issue and we can troubleshoot it step-by-step.

Answer (score 4):

What does the ‘Host‘ variable contain on the server side? The issue might be a incorrect address binding, which prevents the service from being reachable from IP addresses other than localhost (127.0.0.1). Try entering 0.0.0.0 there.